# iOS - SoundCloud - Integration number of frameworks (Sound cloud) in workspace

Tags: ios, git, soundcloud

I know that CocoaSoundCloudAPI has no longer pull request support. But as per my project requirement it is necessary to use this api.

I'm following - https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI

I have created workspace and getting following WARNINGS and ERRORS

---

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/(account_name)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PrankWorkSpace-cckuzufjvkoglfdwnllxgiisuwot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libJSONKit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/(account_name)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PrankWorkSpace-cckuzufjvkoglfdwnllxgiisuwot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libJSONKit.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/(account_name)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PrankWorkSpace-cckuzufjvkoglfdwnllxgiisuwot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libOHAttributedLabel.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/(account_name)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PrankWorkSpace-cckuzufjvkoglfdwnllxgiisuwot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libOHAttributedLabel.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/(account_name)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PrankWorkSpace-cckuzufjvkoglfdwnllxgiisuwot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSoundCloudAPI.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/(account_name)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PrankWorkSpace-cckuzufjvkoglfdwnllxgiisuwot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSoundCloudAPI.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/(account_name)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PrankWorkSpace-cckuzufjvkoglfdwnllxgiisuwot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSoundCloudUI.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/(account_name)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PrankWorkSpace-cckuzufjvkoglfdwnllxgiisuwot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSoundCloudUI.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCShareViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SplashVC.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCSoundCloud", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_SCUICanceledErrorCode", referenced from:
      ___18-[SplashVC upload]_block_invoke in SplashVC.o
  "_SCUIErrorDomain", referenced from:
      ___18-[SplashVC upload]_block_invoke in SplashVC.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Note : I have followed all the steps given in git Doc.

anyone have idea about this kind of problem.

Thank You.

**-- UPDATE --**

I have configured my Target Build Settings like

Architecture   ->  $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT)

Build Active Architecture Only -> No

Other linker flags -> -all_load - ObjC

Always Search User Paths -> No

Header Search Paths -> recursive

Implicitly link objective-c runtime support  -> No

Comment: Did you try to set your "Implicitly link Objective-C Runtime Support" to "NO"?

Comment: Yep man, i have done same and getting same issue. Thanks dude

Comment: You're welcome, can you also try to add "-all_load" flag (like how you add "-ObjC")

Comment: Hi, Kindly see my updates.